# HTTP request equivalent of `curl --user` parameter?

Tags: python, http, curl, get

I am retrieving events data from [the Mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-events.html). I am able to run this on the command line and get data back:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxx' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.net/events
```

Now I want to script this with Python and requests. I know that it is possible [to make a request using Basic-Auth to get the data via a URL](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication). However, Mailgun says that API keys should be treated like a password, so I'd prefer not to expose API keys directly in the URLs if possible.

Is there any way I can do the equivalent of `curl --user` in requests, to supply the parameter but without exposing it in the URL?

Alternatively, would it be better to try to use `curl` directly inside Python?

Comment: Where do you want to put the password that it won't be exposed? It will still be in the script. What makes you think it's exposed more by putting it in the URL? The `request` library extracts it from the URL and puts it into the HTTP authentication header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add the `auth=('user', 'passwd')` argument to the get method, it has to be a tuple with 2 strings.

```
my_req = requests.get('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.net/events', auth=('user', 'pass')
```